Smooth Shading with square shape ( Head )
I'm a beginner who wants to start making models. When I want to smooth the shading, some strange edges appear. Here's the picture.

[
[

You could remove some vertical edge loops, if it doesn't work please share your file

it fix a little bit , but it still appear
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1boD8VlrnlL3LViBdDTq1o5B5I1-kBnpe/view?usp=drive_link

Select these vertices and go into the Vertex panel (in the top horizontal bar) > Smooth Vertices then tweak the parameters in the Operator Box, it should work.

As @moonboots says you can use the Vertex > Smooth Vertices menu. To select them you can Alt-click on the loop where the ridge is then use Ctrl-Numpad+ once to increase the number of selected loops before using Smooth Vertices. It looks as if Smoothing should be set to around 1.5 for best results.
